# Counting matrices whose entries are 1 or -1 such that rows and columns add up to zero

Tags: combinatorics, matrices

> How many numbers of matrices of order 4×4 with the elements 1 or -1
>   such that the sum of all elements row wise as well as column wise is
>   zero?

Here's an [answer](https://www.quora.com/How-many-numbers-of-matrices-of-order-4-4-with-the-elements-1-or-1-such-that-the-sum-of-all-elements-row-wise-as-well-as-column-wise-is-zero).
Can we get an alternative easier approach which may lead to generalization of such type of matrices for any given order?

Comment: If the matrix is $n\times n$ with an odd $n$, the number is clearly zero because the row sum is congruent to $n$ modulo $2$.

Comment: @user1551 Great. We are hence reduced to the even cases. What can be done further?